# Build jar file with Gatling tests only with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to build jar file with [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tests which eventually I need to pass to [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Gatling/) but it seems that my jar is to fat and it clashes with internal libraries in Taurus.

So I think I need to pack only my test files and no other dependencies.

I played with `sbt assembly`  but it seems that it packs 'to much' into the jar file and I can't figure out how to limit it to avoid dependencies like gatling itself.

My general project structure is similar to [this](https://github.com/rolandtritsch/gatling-load-testing) repo. I don't have `main` folder in the repo (do I need to have it?)

Could `sbt native packager` help me here?

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://github.com/michalsi/gatling-jar-tests) is repo which I use to test assembling

Test files that I want to include are in `src/it`

My `build.sbt` (not sure if all makes sense in this context)

```
enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
// This forbids including Scala related libraries into the dependency
autoScalaLibrary := false

// dependencies for Gatling
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.0.2" % Provided
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "3.0.2" % Provided

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)

// make '~' work (again :))
watchSources += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "it"

// configure the assembly
fullClasspath in assembly := (fullClasspath in GatlingIt).value
mainClass in assembly := Some("io.gatling.app.Gatling")
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case path if path.endsWith("io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
  case path => {
    val currentStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    currentStrategy(path)
  }
}
test in assembly := {}
```

The result when I do `sbt assembly` is that I still can see lots of libraries - including Gatling's in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. The assembly plugin it seems to package to much.

You can do the follow:

1. exclude scala library if on your execution environment are already installed.
   You can do this adding the following code to build.sbt

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

2. Setup the dependency that are already installed on your execution environment as Provided. For example

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1" % Provided
```

Comment: thanks @gccodec for reply. I set `libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.0.2" % "test,it" % Provided` in my build.sbt but now I'm getting error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Configurations already specified for module io.gatling:gatling-test-framework:3.0.2:test,it`

Comment: can you add your build.sbt file? In this case the problem is that you already specified a configuration like "test,it". You need to change "test,it" with Provided. For example: ` libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.0.2" % Provided `

Comment: Updated my post with build.sbt file

Comment: Ok man. Pheraps I confused a little bit. 
Gatling is only for test scope so you need to change the kind of scope from Provided to Test.
I try to replicate your build.sbt with a simple project and on assembly phase I only have my MainApp scala class on the file jar with obviously the META-INF file.